# Make Exercise/Answer Tables Correspond

Tags: tables, random-numbers

How do I set this up so that when the random numbers generate the exercises, they also automatically generate the answers for the answer table?

Do I need to revamp the whole thing or can I make a more minor tweak?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartA}{int(random(0,9))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartB}{int(random(0,9))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA+\PartB)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(1,3)}
}

\newcommand{\Blank}{\rule[-3pt]{15pt}{.5pt}}

\newcommand{\onefact}
{
 \InitVariables
 \ifcase\Structure\relax %
  \or
   \def\Question{$\PartA+\PartB=\Blank$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
  \or 
   \def\Question{$\PartA+\Blank=\Sum$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
  \or
   \def\Question{$\Blank+\PartB=\Sum$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
 \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\onefact \Question & \onefact \Question & \onefact \Question \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Answers to the Above Exercises}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\onefact \Answer & \onefact \Answer & \onefact \Answer\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

That code yields the following. Of course, I don't want random numbers to be generated *a second time* for the answers, I just want the completed equations from the exercises to be the answers.

Ideally, I would not have to type out a separate answer table either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **Answers** section will always *follow* your **Questions** section, then the following is a sufficient start. The principle behind the solution is to mark each `\NewQuestion{<tag>}` with a `<tag>`. This stores the answer associated with `<tag>` in a macro, which you can recall later.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartA}{int(random(0,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartB}{int(random(0,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA+\PartB)}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(0,2)}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Blank}{\rule[-3pt]{15pt}{.5pt}}

\newcommand{\Answer}[1]{$\csname Answer_#1\endcsname$}
\newcommand{\NewQuestion}[1]
{%
  \InitVariables
  \expandafter\xdef\csname Answer_#1\endcsname{\PartA + \PartB = \Sum}%
  \ifcase\Structure\relax %
      \let\PartA\Blank
    \or
      \let\PartB\Blank
    \or
      \let\Sum\Blank
  \fi
  $\PartA + \PartB = \Sum$
}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{tabular}{ @{}lll }
  \NewQuestion{first} & \NewQuestion{2} & \NewQuestion{last}
\end{tabular}

\section{Answers to the Above Exercises}
\begin{tabular}{ @{}lll }
  \Answer{first} & \Answer{2} & \Answer{last}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I removed some of the redundant code as there was a number of duplication that is not needed. There were also some [spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) removed.

If you want to be able to refer to the **Answers** *before* the **Questions**, one can use the `\label`-`\ref` system to retrieve this content.

Comment: Ok, cool. I think I will be able to make sense of this when I take a closer look later tonight or tomorrow.  Before then, though, would I stick with your method if I wanted to make, say, 100 questions?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: It would be possible to set up the `\Answer` macro to just print answers in a sequential way that would match the order of the `\NewQuestion`. That way you won't have to provide a `<tag>`. Or, one could make the `<tag>` optional (in both cases; for `\NewQuestion` and `\Answer`).

Comment: And is there a reasonably easy way to not have to make two tables?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything: Sure, but you'll have to be specific regarding the input. With `\NewQuestion` you control how many questions by setting them each separately. A macro like `\SetAnswers` could be used to set all answers to all questions without having to specify the structure...

Comment: Took a closer look and now I have a bunch more questions! (1) What does `\DeclareRobustCommand` mean? (2) Why is there an underscore in `Answer_#1`? (3) What does `\expandafter` do? (4) Why do the column settings in the tables have `@{}`?